# Memory Hierarchy and storing data in caches

Tags: cpu-cache

Question: How many 32 bit integers can be stored in a 16 bit cache line.
Answer: 4

can somebody please explain for me why the answer is 4 i did not understand the reason and i think they should give us more given like the number of blocks in the cache..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a typo there: it's not 16 *bits* but rather 16 *bytes*. Each 32 bit integer takes 4 bytes, so 16/4 = 4.